# Django GET method. Local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: django

I have a problem with Django.

My error message:

**UnboundLocalError at /city/city
local variable 'adv_city' referenced before assignment**

Traceback: http://dpaste.com/751727/

views:

```
def advert_by_city(request):
    c = request.GET.get('city', '')
    if c:
        adv_city = Advert.objects.filter(city=c)

    adverts = Advert.objects.values('city').distinct()
    return render_to_response('advert_by_city', {'adverts':adverts},{'adv_city':adv_city}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template:

```
{% for city in adverts %}
    <a href="city?{{ city.city }}"/>{{city.city}}</a>
<br/>
{% endfor %}

{% for adverts in adv_city%}
    {{adverts.title}}
{% endfor%}
```

model:

```
class Advert(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a default value for `adv_city` in case `c` evaluates to false. For instance, an empty list might work in your case:

```
c = request.GET.get('city', '')
adv_city = Advert.objects.filter(city=c) if c else []
```

If you don't do that, and `c` is false (Python treats the empty string as false, as you may know), then the `adv_city` variable will not be considered assigned.

If you **can** have a valid `Advert` with an empty string as the `city` attribute, then just remove the `if` and let the filter run for any value of `c`.

Comment: Now I have error:render_to_string() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given) http://dpaste.com/751737/

Comment: @pagepydj This is unrelated to the previous problem. See the docs for [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response), probably what you mean is: `return render_to_response('advert_by_city', {'adverts':adverts,'adv_city':adv_city}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`. (If you want to also pass the `c` object to the template, fine, but do that as another field in the dictionary, not as a separate argument)

Answer (score 1):

You should log the value of `c`, i think your code it's not reaching the code inside the `if`, if you give it a default in `request.GET.get('city','')`, the empty string wont go iside the `if`